# Microsoft Access: ¿como conseguir equivalencias españolas a fórmulas en inglés?

Tags: ms-access-2010

Tengo varias fórmulas para Microsoft Access escritas en inglés que me gustaría usar en mi Access versión española.
He tratado de buscar equivalencias, pero incluso la ayuda oficial de access en español, menciona dichas fórmulas en inglés.

¿Alguna solución que no sea desinstalar access para instalar la versión inglesa? ¿se puede tener un access en un idioma insertando fórmulas en otro?

Gracias.

Comment: sé a lo que te refieres, en teoría funcionan tranquilamente entre ambos idiomas. Te sale algún error? o simplemente no se ejecutan las funciones?

Answer (score 1):

Yo tengo Access en español y uso fórmulas inglesas sin ningún problema. Lo único a lo que debes estar atento y en lo que sí he tenido problemas es en las fechas que en español solemos usar `dd-MM-yyyy` y en inglés suele ser `MM-dd-yyyy`. Si usaras las fórmulas en español también tendrías el mismo problema.

Comment: Ese era mi problema, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Josías: Cuando recibes una respuesta que resuelve tu problema, y esta es la única, lo usual es marcarla como mejor respuesta. Más detalles en [Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)